# Regular expression to validate username section in email

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regular expression in java to validate usernames against these criteria:

- it can be started with alphanumeric character or _ or - or.
- it should contain atleast two alphanumeric character at any position before @ symbol
- after @ simple domain name validation

Example

- __z@gmail.com invalid(because only one alphanumeric character before @)
- z@gmail.com invalid(because only one alphanumeric character before @)
- __zz@gmail.com valid
- Z_Z@gmail.com valid

I have created something like below one but it is not working for me.
`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of using a lookahead is correct, but you are using `.` inside it, and `.` matches any character but line break characters. What you need is to restrict it to only match characters other than `@`. Also, the `{2}` limiting quantifier is applied to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` character class only, to match a disjoint alphanumeric twice, you need to group the characters other than alphanumeric and the alphanumeric char pattern.

So, it can look like

```
^(?=(?:[^@a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dsF3yE/1).

However, it might not be a usable email regex for many cases, mind that the simplest pattern to match a "potential" email is `^[^\s@]+@\S+$`, and if you want to apply the same restriction to this pattern, it would look like `^(?=(?:[^@a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2})[^\s@]+@\S+$`.

*Some details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[^@a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){2})` - a positive lookahead that matches two consecutive occurrences of the following sequence: zero or more chars other than ASCII letters and digits and `@` (`[^@a-zA-Z0-9]*`) and then an ASCII alphanumeric (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+` - one or more ASCII letters, digits, underscores, dots or hyphens, then a `@` char, and then again one or more ASCII letters, digits, underscores, dots or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.